# Accessing DOM elements within JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I am looping over an array and outputting a form for each entry in the array.  I am also including a button with each form that toggles the state of each input element, to show/hide them.  I want to connect each button to its parent form and only show/hide elements in each respective form.  I could easily do this with some jQuery, but I want to do it the proper React way, and manage it through state. Any thoughts on where to start?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I read the "how-to-ask" link, but I'm not sure what I did wrong.  Should I add some code?

Comment: you are looking for something in react called refs

Comment: I think what I might need are dynamic variables?  Is that a hack?  Does that go against best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) binding in React, this allows you to access a DOM element programatically. Here's an example.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nodeRef = React.createRef();
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
  }

  doSomething() {
     const node = this.nodeRef.current;

     // Do something with the node
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.nodeRef} onClick={this.doSomething} />;
  }
}
```